# Taking Date and Time Values from Single CustomView

Tags: android, datepicker, android-custom-view, timepicker

I have implemented DatePicker and TimePicker in android.

Now, As we know that DatePicker prompts user to give input only for specific date, same as TimePicker prompts user to give input only for specific time. But, I require to make a single CustomView that handle to take date and time both as input from user.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker Check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Project Sample Which has both Date And Time Picker Together.

You can find a DateTimePicker implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/)

Comment: Great Boss, Working very well.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime Picker

Hope [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) helps...